# Julia hangs on exceptions in HTTP WebSocket block

Tags: http, exception, websocket, julia

I am new to Julia and am encountering some weird behavior when trying to throw exceptions while listening to a WebSocket stream. For example, the following code snippet will hang forever after printing the connection message:

```
using HTTP

HTTP.WebSockets.open("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime") do ws
    message = String(readavailable(ws))
    println(message)
    error("This is an error")
end
```

This is also freezing if an undefined variable is being referenced (this is how I first encountered the problem).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, it looks like it comes from the `HTTP` package. The `close` function hangs because the server keeps sending messages (https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/blob/2a03ca76376162ffc3423ba7f15bd6d966edff9b/src/WebSockets.jl#L237).

Switching from `HTTP` to `WebSockets` solves the issue:

```
using WebSockets

WebSockets.open("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime") do ws
    data, success  = readguarded(ws)
    message = String(data)
    println(message)
    error("This is an error")
end
```